# How to put a POST request on hold in Java if it contains a an ID that is already being processed

Tags: java, api, post

So we are responsible for creating customizations in a third party application using their base code in Java and we need to create a POST API. With the POST a JSON message is send containing data an a product object, and in that JSON message you have the attribute "ItemID" which is its unique identifier. Once received our code with use this message to either create or update said object on our side in the base application. The base application has built an API library that we use for this, which for some reason does not allow more than one parameter for POST request (important for any possible solutions). The issue is that in testing we noticed that often times the client-side is POST multiple request miliseconds apart on the same object, and this causes the base application for work on the same obejct at the same time, causing conflicts, or creating the same obejct twice because the second request is faster at checking if the object existed than the first was at creating that object the first time. So this is (partly) the code that we wrote:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

    @POST
    @Path("ObjectItem")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject processObjectItem(String JSON) throws Exception {
        
        JSONObject jData = new JSONObject(JSON);
       
        JSONArray jItems = jData.getJSONArray("Items");
        JSONObject productItem = jItems.getJSONObject(0);
        
        Long id = productItem.getLong("ItemID");
        Product productBean = new productBean(productItem);

        
        Asset product = getProductById(id);
        if (product == null) {
            createProduct(id, productItem);
        } 
        else {
            updateProduct(id, productItem);
        }

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        result.put("status", "success");
        result.put("message", "Items processed successfully");
        return result;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to best resolve conflicts like the one I described above? A way to put a POST request in a queue if the "ItemID" is already being processed?

We tried a Async method and a POST id that contains the ID in the path but the base application does not allow more an one parameters for POST methods. We just need the code to handle fast requests that use the same ID and make sure they get processed in the order and not at the same time.

Comment: You have a concurrent access issue with regards to your storage. This has nothing to do with the REST requests. What is the code in `createProduct` and `updateProduct`?

Comment: They don't exist, it mock code. They represent code that will create or update an asset in the base application using it's base code (we don't develop that). The problem we encounter now is that client is sending messages with the same itemID within milliseconds of eachother. Meaning that any checks we do (like the getProductByID check) will something take place at almost the same time. Two message could find that a product does not exist and will both create the product.

Comment: "We just need the code to handle fast requests that use the same ID and make sure they get processed in the order and not at the same time." - What prevents you from implementing this code?

Comment: "The problem we encounter now is that client is sending messages with the same itemID within milliseconds of eachother." If the problem is with the client then fix it there. The way I see it, the client can call whenever it wants and it's on the server to handle that. You can either not accept calls from the same client in a chosen duration, or make your code run concurrently properly. You can start by making those mocked methods `synchronized`, but there's not enough info to know what needs to be done.

Comment: Of synchronized methods, you could insert and configure a "web filter" to the servlet and synchronized at that point.